# PHP - Slice nested array

Tags: php, arrays, recursion

I have two nested arrays with different length. I want to make length of second array as per first array, see below examples to get idea. Just remove all those items which don't exist in first array. Sometime second array has more values then first array, in this case my tree structure breaks.
These arrays are nested array so simple array_slice not working.

Here are the structure of array.

> First Array

```
 "1": {
    "id": "1",
    "username": "username",
    "children": [
      {
        "id": "-1",
        "username": "NULL",
        "children": [
          {
            "id": "-1",
            "username": "NULL",
            "children": [
              {
                "id": "-1",
                "username": "NULL",
                "children": []
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

> Second Array

```
"157": {
    "id": "157",
    "username": "test1",
    "children": [
      {
        "id": "158",
        "username": "test1",
        "children": [
          {
            "id": "159",
            "username": "test2",
            "children": [
              {
                "id": "160",
                "username": "test3",
                "children": []
              },
              {
                "id": "160",
                "username": "KICK ME BECAUSE I M NOT EXIST IN FIRST ARRAY",
                "children": []
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": "160",
        "username": "KICK ME BECAUSE I M NOT EXIST IN FIRST ARRAY",
        "children": [
          {
            "id": "159",,
            "username": "KICK ME BECAUSE I M NOT EXIST IN FIRST ARRAY",

            "children": [
              {
                "id": "161",
                "username": "KICK ME BECAUSE I M NOT EXIST IN FIRST ARRAY",
                "children": []
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }

    ]
  }
```

> Expected Output

```
"157": {
    "id": "157",
    "username": "test1",
    "children": [
      {
        "id": "158",
        "username": "test1",
        "children": [
          {
            "id": "159",
            "username": "test2",
            "children": [
              {
                "id": "160",
                "username": "test3",
                "children": []
              },

            ]
          }
        ]
      },
    ]
  }
```

I am trying this method, but it is not working.

```
        $firstCount = (array_map('count', $actualTree));
        $secondCount = (array_map('count', $emptyTree));
        $chunk =  array_slice($actualTree, 0 , $second[$this->userId], true);
```

> Use Case

The thing which I want to do is that remove those array childrens completely which are not exists in first array. I am building a binary tree upto three levels. First array already has a binary tree with empty values. The second array is data that is coming from the database, and I am simply replacing empty data with the actual data using array_replace. This is working good until second array has more values then first array. So to make it working I have to remove those extra elements.

Could anyone please help me to make there length same. Any help will be appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: First array is invalid. Why do you mean by `length` of nested array, total number of keys or depth of array?

Comment: Hi @Tajniak. I just want to make second array depth same as first. I think I missed structure somewhere. You can take this array as reference.

Comment: Please fix your code and paste sample output you want to achieve.

Comment: array_merge() could be a solution?

Comment: "I want to make there length identical.".  It's very unclear what you mean by that, Please clarify!

Comment: Hi @bestprogrammerintheworld. See I have two array. $emptyTree and $actualTree. I want to make length or depth of $actualTree same as $emptyTree. No matter how large is $actualTree, just make it same length as $emptyTree. Please note that structure is same for both arrays.

Comment: Please supply the expected output based on your two arrays. Im struggling to understand exactly what you want and the expected output would make this a lot clearer.

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld, lets take first array as expected output, note the depth of array, first array is smaller then second array. This is what i want. I want to make second array structure similar to first array. If second array has extra values then first then simply remove them.

Comment: Can you please edit your question and the expected result as well thank you?

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld. I have updated the question and added the expected results. Please have a look. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Is there any significance to the `1` and `-1`? If so, I don't see it.

Comment: They are just ids, don't bother them. The main thing we need is structure. I want to make second array structure exactly like first.

Comment: So you want to extract values and maintain the length of children-key only? (If children has 2 in empty, then should have two children in second array).

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld. No that is not the case. The only thing which I want to do is that remove those array childrens completely which are not exists in first array. I am building a binary tree upto three levels. First array already has a binary tree with empty values. The second array is data that is coming from the database, and I am simply replacing empty data with the actual data using array_replace. This is working good until second array has more values then first array. So to make it working I have to remove those extra elements.

Comment: @Neeraj - Ok I think I got it. I will look at it when I have a little more time. I don't have so much right now. Please update your code to include what your code actually does. You say in comment you're using array_replace but you don't include that in your question.

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld, did you get a chance to solve my problem? I am waiting for your response. Please see if you can provide me an answer.

Comment: @Neeraj We see what you want when the second array is too long, but what do you want when the second array is too short?

Comment: @mickmackusa, i don't want anything when second array is short, because everything working fine in that scenario. Thanks for asking.

Comment: This explanation, I feel, is an essential detail for volunteers who may entertain helping you (I am considering helping you) and should be presented in the question body.

Comment: @mickmackusa. Sorry I missed it. The array has complex structure and I'm afraid about the possibility of answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Stack Overflow miracle has occurred... I got a recursive snippet to work on the first pass!  Usually it takes me a good hour or two to write something that works.

I don't know if I can make it any tighter/better OR if it will fail on any fringe cases, but:

1. it works for your sample input
2. it is midnight for me, I'm tired, and I have to work in the morning

Effectively, it synchronously & recursively iterates each array and stores each level of the entry array to the output array so long as the same level keys exists in the structure array.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/gbs9Y))

```
function truncateRecursive($structure, $entry) {
    $output = [];
    while (($structureKey = key($structure)) !== null && ($entryKey = key($entry)) !== null) {
        $output[$entryKey] = !is_array($entry[$entryKey])
            ? $entry[$entryKey]
            : truncateRecursive($structure[$structureKey], $entry[$entryKey]);
        unset($structure[$structureKey], $entry[$entryKey]);    
    }
    return $output;
}

var_export(truncateRecursive($structure, $entry));
```

Output:

```
array (
  157 => 
  array (
    'id' => '157',
    'username' => 'test1',
    'children' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        'id' => '158',
        'username' => 'test1',
        'children' => 
        array (
          0 => 
          array (
            'id' => '159',
            'username' => 'test2',
            'children' => 
            array (
              0 => 
              array (
                'id' => '160',
                'username' => 'test3',
                'children' => 
                array (
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

Comment: really thanks for your help bro. I am too close now. It is giving wrong output for first children. I will see why it is not working in that item. really thanks for your help.

Comment: I am swamped at work, but if you give me a 3v4l demo of the sample data that breaks my script, I'll have another look, but it may be a couple days until I am free.  Please deliver the sample data in the same instantly usable format as I have done in my demo -- `var_export()` is your friend.

Comment: sure bro. I will try to fix it, but if it stucks, then I will create a sample for you at 3v4l.